# integrate an ASP.NET application with SugarCRM

Tags: php, asp.net, md5, sugarcrm

I need to integrate an ASP.NET application with SugarCRM, an Open Source CRM implementation (a very good one).

SugarCRM publishes a SOAP API, but I need to send the password in MD5 format compatible with the MD5 function of PHP as SugarCRM is built on PHP.

In PHP the MD5 function receives a string and returns a hexadecimal number of length 32.

How do i proceed with it?

Answer (score 0):

That's the session_id. Use it on subsequent calls as specified in the API.